# Using twitterAPI to extract twitter data by premium search

Tags: python, twitter

I use TwitterAPI to extract twitter data, but I have an SyntaxError: invalid Syntax when I run python. I'm not a coding expert. Anyone can help me to figure out?´

```py
 for page in api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), {'query'=keyword, count=200, include_rts=False, since=start_date}).pages(50):
       for status in page:
           new_entry = []
           status = status._json
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with your code. Here is an improved version of it:

```
for status in api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
                          {'query'=keyword, 'count'=100, 'include_rts'=False, 'since'=start_date}):
    # "status" returned by api.request is already a json object
    # so you can print the screen name and text from the status like this:
    print(status['user']['screen_name'] + ":" + status['text'])
```

Outline of my changes:

I changed the variable name `page` to `status`, for clarity, since `api.request` returns an iterator that returns statuses.

Just as you did with the key name `query`, all names must be quoted.

The maximum value of `count` is 100.

The object returned by api.request has no method called `pages`. If you want to get successive pages of tweets, you should look at this example https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py

Comment: Thanks so much for your correction. As far as I understand, I'm only able to get maximum 100 tweets per request right? I wonder if Twitter Counts tweet that match my query or payload of tweets. For example, I want to extract data with a specific hastag in English only. Will twitter Counts number of tweets that match my hashtag regardless the language or its Counts number of tweets that match my hashtag in English?

Comment: Actually, up to 100 tweets. Often it will be fewer because Twitter removes spam from the 100 tweets. If you want just English you can add 'lang=en' to your parameters. It's not perfect. All this info you can read in the documentation here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html